# Symfony CollectionType only saves last submitted new item

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

So I have problem with my CollectionType in my Custom Form Type. When I add two new forms to the Collection and properly fill them out and submit. Only the last option is being submitted. I've been banging my head for the last four hours trying to figure this out.

```
class CustomType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(...)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'collection',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'required' => false,
                'entry_type' => CustomItemType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'label' => 'Some label',
                'by_reference' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'empty_data' => new CustomItem(),
                    'by_reference' => false
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(...)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => CustomContainer::class]);
    }
}
```

If you need more information just ask and I will provide. I've implemented the adding of the subforms using jQuery and the prototype provided by the CollectionType class. I followed the tutorial on symfony.com and I'm at a loss at this point on what direction to go in. Any help is appreciated.

I did do some debugging of the form and the data is submitted correctly but when it goes to hydrate the form object it passes the last item in the form for every entry that was added.

***EDIT***

```
function addItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var collectionSelector = $(this).data('collection-selector');
    var list = $(collectionSelector);

    var counter = list.data('widget-counter');

    var newWidget = list.data('prototype');
    var newHtmlElem = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);

    var newElem = $(newHtmlElem);

    newElem.on('click', e.data.removeButtonClass, {itemContainerClass: e.data.itemContainerClass}, removeItem);

    counter++;
    list.data('widget-counter', counter);

    var accordianContainer = $(collectionSelector + ' ' + e.data.collapse);
    newElem.appendTo(accordianContainer);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').tooltip({selector: '.custom-tooltip'});

    $('.add-custom-item-btn').click({removeButtonClass: '.remove-custom-item-btn', itemContainerClass: '.custom-item-item', collapse: '#custom-item-accordion'}, addItem);

    $('.remove-custom-item-btn').click({itemContainerClass: '.custom-item-item'}, removeItem);
});
```

This is a snippet of the twig template

```
{% macro printItem(custom_item, index) %}
<div class="panel panel-default custom-item-item">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="custom-item-heading-{{ index }}>
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#custom-item-accordion"
                href="#custom-item-collapse-{{ index }}"
                class="collapsed"
            >
                Custom Item
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="custom-item-collapse-{{ index }}"
        class="panel-collapse collapse"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="custom-item-heading-{{ index }}"
        aria-expanded="false"
    >
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{ form_row(custom_item) }}
            <button type="button" class="remove-custom-item-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as formMacros %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <button type="button" class="add-custom-item-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-collection-selector="#custom-container-fields-list">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="custom-container-fields-list"
        data-prototype="{{ formMacros.printItem(form.collection.vars.prototype, '__name__') }}"
        data-widget-counter="{{ max(form.collection|keys) + 1 }}"
    >
        <div class="panel-group" id="custom-item-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            {% for index, custom_item in form.collection %}
            {{ formMacros.printItem(custom_item, index) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Edit***
I've created a repo that demonstrates this issue with all the classes so you can view it at your liesure. No this is not the actual code but the issue still occurs with it. I'm using PHP 8.1 and symfony 5.4, but all of that is visible in the composer.json file in the repo below. If anyone can shed some light I would really appreciate it. Or if there is a consensus that this is a bug I'll log a bug with symfony but I would rather be sure of that first.

[Repo that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/GatorGuy023/collection-type-issue)

Comment: Could you show your view + javascript code?

Comment: I've updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: Since the issue can be caused at multiple points, please update your question to include the Controller action method(s) that is processing the Form and the related Entities with their associated properties, annotations/attributes/mappings, and setter/adder methods. However the `'empty_data' => new CustomItem(),` doesn't seem right.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to a repo that reproduces the issue. To reproduce the issue create a customer with two contacts and submit. Then go and edit the same customer add two contacts and submit. When ever you have two existing members in the collection and you add two the error occurs.

Comment: Why are you using the `CustomerType.customerContacts` field [`entry_options`](https://github.com/GatorGuy023/collection-type-issue/blob/develop/src/Form/CustomerType.php#L32) you are using?

Comment: It solves another problem I was encountering. If you don't specify the empty_data property it defaults to an empty array and you will encounter problems when it tries to call member functions on it. The by_reference parameter was me throwing stuff at the wall trying to fix things. :-)

Comment: Right, however the value would not be empty, since it is specified in the data object's constructor as an `ArrayCollection` - so not sure why you would think it would or was causing an issue.  There were other issues that I saw in your repo code that I did not feel comfortable providing an answer for this issue. So I hinted at the issue in my comments that was later described by in the answer, to hopefully have you look back through the tutorial. Technically the `empty_data` is not needed at all, so the answer is partially right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be caused by this line in your `CustomType`:

```
'empty_data' => new CustomItem(),
```

Since you've set `empty_data` to a single instance of `CustomItem`, this same instance is being re-used for each new row.

You've also set `by_reference` to false on the `CollectionType`, which means the adder method on your `CustomContainer` class is being called with this same  `CustomItem` instance for each new row. Assuming you've used the `make:entity` command, this adder method only adds the `CustomItem` object if the same instance does not already exist in its array, which explains the missing items.

The solution is to create a new `CustomItem` instance for each new row, as in the example here:
https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/ (under `The empty_data Option`)

```
'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
    return new CustomItem();
},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I knew it had something to do with that but I was completely unaware/didn't think of passing an anonymous function to that option. Thank you again!